# Usage of forceTK in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, forcetk

I was following the forceTK [documentation](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit) and included forceTK and jQuery into lightning component:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.JavascriptRESTToolkit,$Resource.jQueryMin_2_2_4)}" />
```

However, when I try to create the client in controller, nothing happens:

```
var client = new forcetk.Client();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I was thinking if it can be caused by locker service preventing to load forcetk library, but I'm not sure about this. There should be no problem with jQuery library as the used version is locker service compatible.

Comment: Did you check the browser console for any errors?
If you don't see any errors, you may use the `afterScriptsLoaded` in the `ltng:require` tag, just to make sure the resources has finished loading and check it's functionality there. If you've done this too, then please post the whole code.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried it and `console.log(jQuery);` works while `console.log(forcetk);` does not. So it seems that forcetk is really not loaded and I will have to do it using Visualforce page in an iframe.

Comment: Oh. One more thing if `forcetk` requires `jQuery` mandatorily, then try changing the order in which it's being loaded(First load jQuery, followed by forcetk).

Comment: Makes sense, but doesn't work unfortunately. Anyway, thanks for ideas!

Comment: Hi, did you find solution for forcetk library to work in Lightning, other than putting it in VF iFrame, if yes please share, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I did not find any other solution and had to use iFrame approach.

Comment: FYI, `lightning:fileUpload` base component, capable of uploading 2GB file, was just introduced in Winter18. I did not test it yet and therefore cannot compare it to forceTK, but definitely promising! https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_fileUpload.htm